# Logstash keep creating field despite the dynamic_mapping being deactivated

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping, logstash

I have defined my own template to be used by logstash where I have deactivate the dynamic mapping:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "order": 0,
        "template": "my_index",
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "mapper": {
                    "dynamic": "false"
                },
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "nlp_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "nlp_tokenizer"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "nlp_tokenizer": {
                            "pattern": ""
                            "(\w+)|(\s*[\s+])"
                            "",
                            "type": "pattern"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "0"
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "author": {
                "properties": {
                    "author_name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "author_pseudo": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "author_location": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "standard": {
                                "analyzer": "standard",
                                "term_vector": "yes",
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "nlp": {
                                "analyzer": "nlp_analyzer",
                                "term_vector": "yes",
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To test if elasticsearch won’t generate new field I try to let a field in my events that is not present in my mapping, let’s say that I have this event:

```
{
“type” => “author”,
“author_pseudo” => “chloemdelorenzo”,
“author_name” => “Chloe DeLorenzo”,
“author_location” => “US”,
}
```

Elasticsearch will generate a new field in the mapping when indexing this event:

```
"type": {
     "type": "text",
      "fields": {
           "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
           }
      }
 }
```

I know that Logstash is using my template because in my mapping I use a custom analyser and I can find it back into the mapping generated. But apparently it doesn’t take into consideration that the dynamic field is disabled.

I want elasticsearch to ignore fields that are not present in my mapping but to index the field that have a defined mapping. How can I avoid logstash to create new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enforce the mapping at the document type level.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html

> Regardless of the value of this setting, types can still be added
>   explicitly when creating an index or with the PUT mapping API.

So your mapping will look like:

```
"mappings": {
    "author": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "author_name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "author_pseudo": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "author_location": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "standard": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "term_vector": "yes",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "nlp": {
                        "analyzer": "nlp_analyzer",
                        "term_vector": "yes",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not exactly what you are requesting, but you can manually remove fields with a logstash filter like this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["fieldname"]
  }
}
```

If your events have a defined list of fields, you could solve your problem this way.

Comment: Yeah I know but I may have a lot of unexpected field coming through so it's a solution I cannot afford

Comment: what about the `prune` filter? it allows you to whitelist good fields instead of blacklisting them. Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html

Comment: I think I find a solution without using an other plugin. I  enforce the dynamic mapping at the document type level:

`..."author": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {...`